# Fetch Certain Number of random Rows Belonging to Different Tables into One Result Set?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

See the Tables : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FitK.png

Can anyone help me with constructing a query that will fetch random questions based on the category and difficulty level and the total number of questions set in the Question Set Config. table.

I have constructed one.

```
SELECT c.question_id
, s.question_set_id 
FROM qm_question_category c
, qm_question_set_cfg s
WHERE ( c.category_id = s.category_id 
AND c.difficulty_level = s.difficulty_level
) 
AND ROWNUM <= (SELECT SUM(total_questions) 
FROM qm_question_set_cfg 
WHERE question_set_id = 101138) /* Set ID */
ORDER BY dbms_random.value
```

This fetches the total number of questions randomly from the existing questions based on the categories and difficulty level.

But what I want is to first fetch the questions in each category + difficulty randomly and then merge those rows into one single result set. (For eg. 10 questions random from Category1, 10 from Category2 upto the 10 from CategoryN as set in the Question Set Config)

Comment: The query you've created will not randomize the results. The `ROWNUM` in the where clause will be applied before the `ORDER BY` statement. While the result is not guaranteed to be consistent, it's unlikely to actually be random either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `order by` like this:

```
order by rank() over (partition by c.category_id order by dbms_random.value)
```

What I'm trying to do is random the order of the records for every category by its own and then oredr it so it will be -

```
category a
category b
category c
category a
category b
category c
...
```

so now you can fetch 30 records and be sure that you have 10 of category a, 10 of category b and 10 of category c

---

**UPDATE** after reading your comment I realized you may be looking for something like this:

```
select *
  from (select c.question_id,
               c.category_id,
               s.set_id,
               s.no_of_questions,
               rank() over(partition by c.category_id order by dbms_random.value) rank
          from question_category c, question_set_config s
         where c.category_id = s.category_id
           and c.difficulty_level = s.difficulty_level
           and s.set_id = 101138) t
 where rank <= t.no_of_questions
```

I used the rank() analytic function to give a "line number" to each random question within its category. Then I could request only those who're smaller than `no_of_questions`

Comment: How to make sure that it fetch the number of rows set in each category based on 'total_questions'. 

Can you please help me by constructing the full query such that... 

if a Question Set has 2 categories each with difficulty level 1 and 2 respectively and no of questions as 5 and 10 ... It will fetch 5 random questions of category a with difficulty level 1 and 10 random questions of difficulty level 2 and then fetch these (5+10) questions ids in a result set. (see the table diag. in the link to the image)

Comment: Hi A.B.Cade  I was wondering how to fetch all the questions based on all the the set ids... in case if I don't want to specify the set id. 

Removing "and s.set_id = 101138" gives peculiar results... sometimes its fetches 35 rows sometimes 32, or 33 etc.

Comment: I can't check it now, but perhaps you'll have to get the rank() over a partition of both s.set_id and c.category_id. should look like: `rank() over(partition by s.set_id, c.category_id order by dbms_random.value) rank`